# Sitecore 9.2 with JSS installation Error

Tags: jss, installation

I am new in Sitecore and I am working on a project it is in `Sitecore 9.2 and JSS`.

For the installation I am referring to the below URL:
https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore.HabitatHome.Utilities/tree/release/9.2.0
**and readme file:**
https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore.HabitatHome.Utilities/blob/release/9.2.0/docs/xp/readme.md

I am trying to install the Sitecore but I am getting the below error:

[image]

Following mentioned steps I have completed before installation of `Sitecore 9.2`:

1. Installed all the prerequisites
2. Completed the installation of `SOLR 7.5` and it's up and running on URL: https://localhost:8750/solr/#/

Comment: can you check on IIS if you have your site bindings with http ? for me looks like you have it just with https

Comment: @VladIobagiu Its with https bindings,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SIF Script is trying to access a site with http but you have only https in your bindings.

In sitecore-xp0.json you have next definition:

```
"UpdateSolrSchema": {
            "Description": "Update the solr schemas.",
            "Type": "SitecoreUrl",
            "Params": {
                "SitecoreInstanceRoot": "[concat('https://', parameter('DnsName'))]",
                "SitecoreActionPath": "sitecore/admin/PopulateManagedSchema.aspx?indexes=all",
                "UserName": "admin",
                "Password": "[variable('Sitecore.Admin.Password')]"
            }
        }
```

Can you check if you change from http to https . Other solution is to add a http binding to IIS .

Comment: @Bhawana That's not how this site works. Please don't post "thank you" comments, rather use the voting and accept answer mechanics. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers